# PHP MYSQL upload and compress image to Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to upload image to Mysql database with reduced image size. I can upload the image successfully, but can't reduce the size. How can I upload and reduce the image.
For example, uploading an image which size is about 2MB, I want to compress it(Maybe will be less than 1MB) and upload it to Mysql Database.

This is my code:

```
if (isset($_POST['btn-save'])) {
    if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'])) {
        $filename = $_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'];
        $filePath = $_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'];
        $image1 = imagecreatefrompng($filePath);
        $image2 = imagecreatefromgif($filePath);
        $exif = exif_read_data($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']);
        if (!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
            $imageResource = imagecreatefromjpeg($filePath);
            switch ($exif['Orientation']) {
                case 3:
                    $image = imagerotate($imageResource, 180, 0);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    $image = imagerotate($imageResource, -90, 0);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    $image = imagerotate($imageResource, 90, 0);
                    break;
                default:
                    $image = $imageResource;
            }
        }
        imagejpeg($image, $filename, 20);
        imagedestroy($imageResource);
        imagedestroy($image);
        imagejpeg($image1, $filename, 50);
        imagedestroy($image1);
        imagejpeg($image2, $filename, 50);
        imagedestroy($image2);
        $imgData = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']));
        $imageProperties = getimagesize($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name']);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO Database (imageType, imageData) VALUES('{$imageProperties['mime']}', '{$imgData}')";
        $current_id = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("<b>Error！</b> <br/>" . mysqli_error());
        if (isset($current_id)) {
            echo "post";
        } else {
            echo "fail";
        }
    }
} // post btn-save
```

Comment: Don't expect that kind of savings, GIF JPEG amd PNG already compress their data  I just zipped a PNG and it only went from 62K down to 51K.  One approach would be to use PHP's Zip class then add that Zip.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to store the image in a database?  It is definitely not best practice to store files in a database.  I'd advise a slightly different approach.  Basically, you will move the file to a folder, rename it to keep it unique, and then save its path in the database.  This way you are only querying a short string as opposed to a potentially large piece of data.

Comment: @Luke, This is a good suggestion. Thanks.